# Merging files tree with parent Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

## Context

I have the following files tree:

```
.
|-- Parent
|   |-- root
|   |   |-- foo
|   |   |   |-- a
|   |   |   `-- b
|   |   `-- bar
|   `-- Dockerfile
`-- Child
    |-- root
    |   |-- foo
    |   |   |-- c
    |   |   `-- d
    |   `-- baz
    `-- Dockerfile
```

In my parent's Dockerfile, I have:

```
FROM centos:centos7
COPY root /
```

In my child's Dockerfile, I have:

```
FROM Parent
COPY root /
```

---

## Expected

I would hope that the following files are in my child image :

```
/
|-- foo
|   |-- a
|   |-- b
|   |-- c
|   `-- d
|-- bar
`-- baz
```

---

## Result

What I get instead is this incomplete tree:

```
/
|-- foo
|   |-- c
|   `-- d
|-- bar
`-- baz
```

It seems that Docker only merge the top level of the directory:

- It sees that directory foo already exists, and **overrides it in the child**
- It sees that baz doesn't exists, and simply adds it

I guess what I'm after is some kind of recursive logic, where it applies the same behaviour to all directory recursively, instead of stopping and overriding everything after the first level.

---

## Questions

1. Is that currently supported by Docker?
2. If not, is there a workaround, or a best practice?
3. If not, is there anything in the pipeline?

Comment: why not use ADD with a tar.gz? extract from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add I see `If <src> is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory.`

Comment: This sounds like an interesting workaround, if the extraction merges trees correctly. But hearing from @Mark Riggins getting what I want with Docker 1.9.0, I'll first try to upgrade!